# Access modules and module variables at runtime from python via String

Tags: python, import, exec, micropython

In my Python programm I want to dynamically load modules and access variables of the module by converting a string parameter into a variable name.

**Use Case**

I have different Fonts on SD Card which are python files, and a display function which loads the font when needed to display the caracters.

Examples for my font file:

```
# arial14.py
# ch_(ASCII) = (widht), (height), [bitmask]
ch_33 = 3, 16, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1 ........
ch_34 = 5, 16, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ........
....

# arial20.py
ch_33 = 4, 22, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1 ........
ch_34 = 8, 22, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ........
```

Further, there is a Writer class which renders the fonts to the display:

```
class Writer(object):
    def __init__(self):
       try:
           global arial14
           import arial14
           self.current_module = "arial14"
           self.imported_fonts = []
           self.imported_fonds.append(self.current_module)
      except ImportError:
           print("Error loading Font")
   def setfont(self, fontname, fontsize):
           modname = fontname+str(fontsize)
           if modname not in self.importedfonts:
               try:
                    exec("global" + modname)
                    exec("import" + modname)      #import the font (works)
                    self.importedfonts.append(modname)
               except ImportError:
                    print("Error loading Font")
                    return
           else:
               print(modname+" was already imported")
           self.current_module = modname
           print("Font is set now to: "+ self.current_module

## HERE COMES THE NON WORKING PART:
    def putc_ascii(self, ch, xpos, ypos):

           execline = "width, height, bitmap = "+ self.cur_mod+".ch_"+str(ch)
           print(execline) 
           #this example.: width, height,bitmap = arial14.ch_55


           width, height,bitmap = arial14.ch_32
           print(width, height, bitmap) # values of arial14.ch_32 -> correct

           exec (execline)
           print(width, height, bitmap) # values of arial14.ch_32
                                        # BUT VALUES OF arial14.ch_55 EXPECTED
```

Has anybody an idea how can I accomplish to save the correct values of the queried character of the correct font into the variables width, height and bitmap?

I want to load the Fonts dynamically only if needed, and offer the possibility to add new fonts by putting new .py font files into the folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do any of this. Use a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

The OP is actually using micropython, which doesn't implement importlib...

Possible (untested) solution (yes, using `exec` - if someone knows a better solution please chime in).

```
def import_module(name):
    name = name.strip().split(
    statement = "import {}"
    exec(statement, globals()) 
    return sys.modules[name]


class Writer(object):
    def __init__(self):
       # reference to the current module
       # WARNING : this is the `module` object itself, 
       # not it's name       
       self.current_module = None

       # {name:module} mapping
       # not sure it's still useful since we
       # now have a reference to the module itself
       # and `sys.modules` already caches imported 
       # modules... 
       self.imported_fonts = {}

       # set default font
       self.setfont("arial", "14")

    def setfont(self, fontname, fontsize):
        self.current_module = self._loadfont(fontname, fontsize)

    def _loadfont(self, fontname, fontsize):
        name = fontname+str(fontsize)
        if name not in self.imported_fonts:
            self.imported_fonts[name] = load_module(name)
        return self.imported_font[name]

    def putc_ascii(self, ch, xpos, ypos):
        width, height, bitmap = self._get_char(ch)
        print("{}.{}: {} - {} - {}".format(
            self.current_module, ch, width, height, bitmap
            )

    def _get_char(self, chrnum):
        # assume the font modules have been rewritten
        # using dicts (cf lower) and all chars are defined
        # in all fonts modules
        return self.current_module[ch]

        # alternate implementation using the current
        # fonts definitions
        # return getattr(self.current_module, "ch_{}".format(ch))
```

**TL:DR** :

You want `importlib.import_module` and eventually `getattr()`. But you should still read the longer answer, really, it will save you a lot of time and frustration.

**Longer answer**:

First point about your "font" files format - this:

```
ch_33 = 3, 16, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1 ........
ch_34 = 5, 16, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ........
```

is a huge design smell. You want lists or dicts instead (or possibly an ordered dict), ie:

```
characters = {
    33: (3, 16,  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1...]),
    34: (5, 16,  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...]),
    # etc
    }
```

As a general rule, when you start having some "var1", "var2", "var3" etc pattern then you know you want some kind of container instead.

Second  point - your error handling, ie:

```
 try:
       global arial14
       import arial14
       self.current_module = "arial14"
       self.imported_fonts = []
       self.imported_fonds.append(self.current_module)
  except ImportError:
       print("Error loading Font")
```

is worse than useless, it's actually harmful. First because it doesn't stop program execution in the case of an unrecoverable error (you *dont* want your program to continue when something totally wrong happened), then because it replaces all the incredibly useful informations you'd either get from the error message and traceback with a plain useless "An error happened" message.

Only catch exceptions that you can properly manage one way or another, let everything else propagate (maybe someone upper in the call stack - usually in the UI part - might be able to handle it properly).

Third point: do not use globals. I mean: do not mutate nor rebind globals (read-only (pseudo-constant) globals are ok of course). Which means you really never have to use the "global" keyword in your code.

When you need to share state between a group a functions, use a class, store the state as attributes and make your functions methods. That's what objects are for (well, not only but that's part of there raison d'être).

**EDIT** : *this part is still true for complete Python implementation and probably still partly true for micropython, **except** for parts that are not implemented in micropython (like `importlib` - I don't know what else is missing)*

And finally: never ever use `exec` nor `eval`. **You don't need them**, whatever you're trying to do there's a better, safer specific solution.

In your case, to import a module by it's name, you have [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), and to get an object's attribute by it's name you have [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) (but if you use a proper container, cf first point, you don't even need `getattr` here).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With the error handling part you are fully right, I forgot to insert code there. In my original code there is a return statement there. The other points I will consider and adjust the implementation. The problem with importlib is, that I am developping on an embedded device with Micropython, and I think there does not exist this module. But I will try it tomorrow when i'm at my workplace. Is there a way without this module to load modules and variables with not predetermined names at runtime (at the moment I use the REPL to send the command to load and draw fonts).

Comment: Looks like there's no importlib in micropython indeed(judging from this : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/micropython-importlib/0.0.0) . You should really have specified you were working on micropython actually.

Comment: I edited my answer with a possible cleaner implementation, still using `exec` to import fonts (well yes if you don't have `importlib` nor any replacement you can hardly avoid `exec` here)

Comment: Merci beacoup pour votre aide! You´re right, i should have said that i´m developping on Micropython, but I will consider the points in your reply though. Now i figured it out how to solve the problem. Instead of exec which normally returns None (in my case it returns undetermined values) I had to use eval, which is working now. At the moment I have to set the fontname with exec("global "+fontname) to global, but I will try around a  little to keep the variables local.

Comment: De rien - and if this solves your problem then feel free to upvote and accept the answer ;)

Comment: Das ist kein problem ;)